# Update parent from child record Odoo V8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am fighting with odoo V8. I am trying to update stock_picking when stock move is updateted

```
  ##################

_inherit = "stock.move"

supp_date_confirm = fields.Date('Confirmed Date')

@api.model
@api.onchange('supp_date_confirm')
def _onchange_supp_date_confirm(self):

    picking = self._origin.picking_id

    self._origin.picking_id.supp_date_confirm = self.supp_date_confirm
    self.picking_id.supp_date_confirm = self.supp_date_confirm
```

Any ideas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add suggestions as a comment so i'm writing it as an answer:
You can use create and write method of stock move to set values in stock picking.